# Should I downvote an answer that has no meaningful content, other than a link?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, link-only-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

If someone just writes a link on their answer (without any summary), should I downvote? What if the link is useful?

Example: "**[This](http://example.com) pretty much sums it up.**"

[**note**] I've seen one mod down-vote such an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) pretty much sums it up. :)